# Node test not running mongoose function

Tags: javascript

I have a controller which I want to test

```
// user model
const userModel = require('../models/user')

// get user model from handler
const User = userModel.User

function index(req, res) {
  User.find(function(err, users) {
    if (err) console.log(err)

    console.log('debug')

    res.render('../views/user/index', {
      title: 'User index',
      users: users
    })
  })
}

module.exports = {
  index
}
```

using the following code

```
// dependencies
const sinon = require('sinon')

// controller to be tested
const controller = require('../controllers/user')

// get user test
describe('test user index', function() {

  it ('should return users', function() {

    var req = {}
    var res = {
      render: function() {
        sinon.spy()
      }
    }

    controller.index(req, res)

  })
})
```

When I run the test it doesn't execute the `console.log('debug')` which seems to me indicates that the test can't run the `User.find()` function. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary solution, you can include DB connection string at the top of the file.
Explanation: I guess your controller is part of an app, so it connects to DB on init. However, here you are testing an isolated controller, therefore DB connection isn't initialized yet. That's quick solution, for proper way of doing that refer to [official docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mongodb)

Comment: That makes sense. Would it be better if I test my controller from the http requests level. I've been trying to avoid that since I've read that isolated testing is better and http level goes through the routers which feels like more of an integrated testing.

Comment: @Noop It depends on your needs. You can implement both at the same time, however, http-level (from my experience) is mostly used for health-checks versus functional testing.